# Rule - Check for an email with an image tag

Tags: email, spam, outlook, rules, phishing

I hate spammers phising emails, it doesn't contain anything but an image

with  in the body.

I'm wondering if there is a rule, I can check if the email body contains only and only `<img>` and no other texts. I would like to configure them to skip my inbox and auto-delete if possible.

Example

[image]

Sooooo annoying !

Comment: Depending on what messages are actually to be received at that mailbox, a simpler solution may be to stop accepting messages with a sender called "no-reply" altogether.

Comment: The key why this does not work is that as soon as you allow html & css in your inbox, you also allow people to be sneaky about fulfilling any "must contain text" requirement (maybe the message does contain text, just not made obvious by your mail client, e.g. because it was shown at 99% transparency or 1 pixel line height).

Comment: auto-delete `auto-reply` completely, I was thinking about that too.

Comment: Blocking HTML, and accept texts only might be tough since most emails nowadays will be in HTML format. I was looking for away to detect if the body message length == 0 or empty.